# On click new QDailog window overlaps with old window and everything becomes very messy , focus still remain on old window

Tags: qt, qdialog

Overview:
I have designed QPushbutton in some window   which when clicked open a new Dialog Window( Say start_backup_window) .
In this window I have  Designed another  QPushbutton say check_backup_option_button which when clicked should open another Dialog window say ( backup_options_window).

Problem : Everything works as expected  but when I click check_backup_option_button  the new backup_options_window overlaps with previous start_backup_window. I have tried few things but it doesn't work.

Also I have noticed that when I drag old window the new window allows me to do so. Generally it happens that you cant do any thing to old window unless and util you click cancel or ok button in new window.
May you guys please advice me how to proceed.

Below are my code

```
    start_backup_window_old.cpp


#include "backup_options_window.h" 

//  called init() function in the constructor

 start_backup_window::start_backup_window(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent), self_backup_options( 0 )
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    init_cal_signals();
}


void start_backup_window::init_cal_signals()
{

connect( ui.check_backup_option_button, SIGNAL( clicked () ), this , SLOT( open_new_backup_options_window() ) );

}


void start_backup_window::open_new_backup_options_window()
{
    self_backup_options = new backup_options_window( this ); 
    self_backup_options->show();

}
```

Comment: What happens if you call `new backup_options_window;` instead? Without providing 'this' as a parent.

Comment: @vahancho , if I do  as you mentioned , doesnt it mean that I have to call delete somewhere in the code for backup_options_window? Giving "this" as a parameter in the constructor , I thought i dont need to explicitly call delete .. I could be wrong  please let me know your views?

Comment: @vahancho, Also  I expect that when back_option_window gets open , IThe new window shouldn't allow me to  click boxes or buttons on old window unitl and unless i close the new one. but this is not happening currently

Comment: to block interaction with the parent window you should use `self_backup_options->exec()` instead of `show`

Comment: @ratchetfreak  it complains and say exec' : is not a member of 'Self_Calibration_options'.

Comment: @samprat, that is another problem that could be solved later. But let's try to solve the initial issue first - does removing (this) help?

Comment: @vahancho , Yes it has solved the problem ... Thanks a lot ..vahancho

Comment: @vahancho , just one more doubt, How would i solve 2nd problem " the new window shouldn't allow me to click boxes or buttons on old window unitl and unless i close the new one. but this is not happening currently"

Comment: @samprat, please find my extended answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seem to be in setting the parent to the backup_options_window. I suggest to change the code in the following way:

```
void start_backup_window::open_new_backup_options_window()
{
    if (!self_backup_options)
        self_backup_options = new backup_options_window; 
    self_backup_options->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal); // makes the window modal
    self_backup_options->show();
}
```

With this implementation, you will need to delete `self_backup_options` pointer later. For example in destructor of `start_backup_window` class. Please don't forget to initialize the `self_backup_options` to null in the constructor of `start_backup_window` class.

Comment: it did work now  flawlessly.. Thanks a lot .  I will try to read what actually windowModal means ...cheers

Comment: @samprat, I came back and modify my sample code to prevent creation of the `self_backup_options` each time you press the button. In this way, it will be created only once.